# Trying to understand the output of this pipe operation in r

Tags: r

I am learning r and currently am looking at the pipe operator %>%, found in the `magrittr` package.  When I try the following:

```
pi/2 %>% sin
```

The result is `3.454967`, which is incorrect

Instead when I do:

```
(pi/2) %>% sin
```

The result is `1`, which is correct.
I am curious what is happening in the first case, from looking through the documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html). I am unable to find anything useful.  Could someone point me in the direction of some documentation for understanding this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in which functions are evaualted depend on the operator precedence rules descrubed in the `?Syntax` help page

```
:: :::   access variables in a namespace
$ @      component / slot extraction
[ [[     indexing
^        exponentiation (right to left)
- +      unary minus and plus
:        sequence operator
%any%    special operators (including %% and %/%)
* /      multiply, divide
+ -      (binary) add, subtract
< > <= >= == !=  ordering and comparison
!        negation
& &&     and
| ||     or
~        as in formulae
-> ->>   rightwards assignment
<- <<-   assignment (right to left)
=        assignment (right to left)
?        help (unary and binary)
```

Note that `%%` functions have higher precedence then `/` so they are run first. So essentially you are running

```
pi/(2 %>% sin)
# pi/0.9092974
# [1] 3.454967
```